# Structuring a raw JS 'plugin' with prototypes

Tags: javascript

I'm writing a small plugin for a reusable project, but it needs to be initiated, I just am stuck as to how. I've stripped it down to show the bare bones (below):

```
( function ( window, document, undefined ) {

  var Plugin = function ( elem ) {
    this.elem = elem;
  };

  Plugin.prototype = {

    init : function () {
        // init stuff
    }

  };

  var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input');
  for ( var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++ ) {
    new Plugin(inputs[i]).init();
  }

})( window, document );
```

This is about 80% done I would say, I am confused as to where to 'call' the plugin, in few words, the script runs, but I am not calling it.

I need to do something like so:

```
for ( var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++ ) {
    inputs[i].Plugin();
}
```

Which will call it, currently I am just calling the 'new' on the object. Any help as to a proper setup (jQuery style but without jQuery) would be amazing. Thank you!

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ZJdRg/) if needed:

Comment: if it self-executes based upon the HTML markup, you don't need to call it, and in fact, that makes it easier for non-JSy people to use.

Comment: jQuery doesn't modify the prototypes of host objects like `inputs[i]`, which is an `HTMLElement`. It creates its own wrapper function (`$`) that holds all of its functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Extending the DOM is a bad idea](http://perfectionkills.com/whats-wrong-with-extending-the-dom/).

But to make it simpler, move the initialisation stuff to the constructor - that's what constructors are made for:

```
(function (window, document, undefined) {
  function Plugin(elem) {
    this.elem = elem;
    // init stuff
  }
  Plugin.prototype.otherFunctions = …;

  var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input');
  for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++)
    new Plugin(inputs[i]);

})(window, document);
```

Answer (score 3):

Please don’t try to make it fancy.

```
for ( var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++ ) {
    new Plugin(inputs[i]).init();
}
```

is a beautiful and sorely underappreciated API. If you insist, though, you can put `.Plugin()` (which would just do this) on `HTMLElement.prototype`, which would break it in IE7-8.

Also, passing `undefined` to an IIFE is a bad idea.

Comment: If someone happened to redefine `undefined` (it used to work in older browsers), things would start breaking. jQuery does this.

Comment: @Blender: And if someone were to redefine `undefined` inside an IIFE, it would still work in newer browsers.

Comment: @minitech: Never mind that older browsers thing, you can still redefined `undefined`. Passing `undefined` as a parameter makes sure that a redefined `undefined` from an outer scope isn't pulled in by mistake. I'm not sure why you're saying it's a bad idea.

Comment: @Blender: On a decent browser, no, you can’t. Unless you pass it as a parameter. `window.undefined` is a read-only property in ES5, and strict mode actually throws a proper error if you try to overwrite it. If you use an IIFE and pass it in, it’s just a regular argument and can be overwritten without error, even in strict mode.

Comment: @minitech: True. I'm not sure where I remember seeing `undefined` being redefined, but jQuery actually does it to increase compression, as `undefined` will be shortened by the minifier and still point to `window.undefined`.